# How to pass variable from module to other theme

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to pass variables from my custom module to some of my custom themes.
The most tutorials are concerning using hook_theme function but as I understand, it works only for creating new theme functions (new tpl files) inside module, where the hook_theme is defined. But I would need to alter theme definition of some custom theme in 
/sites/all/themes folder from my custom module
/sites/all/modules

In particular, I need to add a variable into thems's html.tpl.php file. I would like to use custom module to define variable, because I need to make database queries to fill variable with value, and db queries should not be done in theme.

I have tried implementing [hook_theme_registry_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).
I have tried to add variable like this:

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
$theme_registry['html']['variables']['test'] = 'test value';
}
```

but I got error "Undefined index: #children in template_process_html"

Can anybody help?

Comment: [template_preprocess_html()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) uses `#children` only in `$variables['page'] = $variables['page']['#children'];` - it should in no way interfere with your code.

Comment: I would use variable_set() & variable_get():
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7

Comment: You right that it will work, altough this isn't the best practice to use those function in that case. See @Beebee answer

Comment: In this case, `variable_set()` should not be used, since the value used by the OP is temporary, while the values saved with `variable_set()` are not temporary. There is also a performance issue, since `variable_set()` clears the cache used for persistent variables, and that is bad, for a value that could change at every page load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your needs, you'll need to create a custom module and implement `hook_preprocess_html`:

```
function hook_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  // This is where you do the db query
  $myvar = _get_my_var(); 

  // After this $myvar will be available in html.tpl.php
  // where you need to print it out
  $vars['myvar'] = $myvar;
}
```

Comment: Would you care a word of insight why `hook_theme_registry_alter` wouldn't work here?, and what might trigger `#children` error message?

Comment: It would work either way, I have no idea why he's getting the error with #children. It could be some leftover code from the other things he tried. Who knows.

Comment: Aren't preprocess function should be used only on the theme level? (I'm asking because this is the first time I see that is should be used at the module level..) Thanks!

Comment: @Rotem well they usually should, but it's a doable workaround for mysterious bug we can't quite nail down... If you can guess / know how to test why sudden `#children` error arises, I'll gladly upvote your answer.

Comment: @Rotem it's true that preprocessors for template themes like html and page and node etc *should* be on theme level, but there's plenty of modules that use preprocessors for their own module's theme functions :) So it all kinda boils down to your use case. OP said that he wants to assign the var in module therefore...